# Compile Multiple .xls files in Shared Drive

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to `compile several daily xls files` into one master file. The location is in a shared folder but I can also copy them to my desktop. I'm using the developer tab in Excel and have researched some other sources online.

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Desktop\test_for_margaret\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
     For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

My VBA knowledge is limited but I figure there is more to change the lines following the Path.

Comment: Did you try this?  If Yes what happened?  If No, that seems like the thing to do first...

Comment: For some reason the macro wont run. The master file is saved as macro enabled but clicking the play button or debug button does not prompt any action from Excel.

Comment: Are you sure there are XLS files in that folder? Are you sure they arent XLSX files?

Comment: i created a test environment (folder) on my desktop and those files are xlsx, the code will reflect this in line 3

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to comment (reputation limit), so I'm posting as an answer.

As braX points out, you are looping through the directory looking for "*.xls" files. If your files are ".xlsx" then you will not be finding any matches.

Update your filename string to be defined as below:

```
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls*")
```

The additional wildcard character will allow you to see both .xls files and .xlsx. Of course, this is provided that the path supplied is correct.

Comment: the code runs now!

if i wanted to add each workbook to the "master workbook" instead of adding it as a sheet within the master file, would that require changing Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) to Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook for example? 

Also, is it possible to modify it to null the first row of each subsequent sheet/workbook after the first sheet in order to exclude the headers? This example is for multiple sheets.

Sub LoopThroughSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

     ws.Range("1:1").Delete

    Next ws
End Sub

Comment: Hopefully you found the answer to your question. I'd consider posting again (or editing your initial question) and someone will happily assist you. It may take some testing for you to get it down. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Compile or merge?  The following script will merge all Excel files in a folder.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm